# Error I am getting while execution in Android Studio 1.4

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting this error while executing

```
Error:(30, 9) error: cannot find symbol class List
Error:(30, 38) error: cannot find symbol class ArrayList
Error:(30, 56) error: cannot find symbol variable Array
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Those look like compiler errors.  Do you have the import statements for those classes?